# CSS not working as expected, it is styling elements that I didnt ask it to style as well

Tags: html, css

I want to select 2 elements inside a div with the class of promotion and make their text color white.

```css
.promotion h1, p {
    color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article class="promotion grid-col-span-3 text-center">
        <h1>Spring Sale!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam voluptatibus laboriosam debitis
                    dolor aut perspiciatis necessitatibus facilis expedita eligendi, accusantium saepe ut dolorum beatae
                    asperiores? Sit velit soluta asperiores perferendis.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

But it selects elements that are outside the article with the class promotion as well.

Comment: the comma separates two selectors. Maybe you meant `.promotion > h1, .promotion > p`

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors are separated by `,`. So that means your CSS has 2 selectors: `.promotion h1` and `p`.

To solve your issue, add `.promotion` to the front of `p`:

```css
.promotion h1,
.promotion p {
    color: #FFF;
}
```